# Convert expression using cout to assignment

Tags: c++

I'm creating a code to read any file as binary and convert to hex. I've found the following code which prints the char as hex. However, I'd like to just set a variable with the result of the conversion. How can I do this?

Current code:

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
                << (int)x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') <<(int)x;
std::string s = ss.str();
```

You need to `#include <sstream>`